# Custom method in hibernate repository

Tags: spring, hibernate, repository

I want to add custom method to hibernate `CrudRepository`. I'm using it with spring framework. [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) said that it is posible, but example show interface not extending `Repository` base class.

I know that there is an annotation `@Query` that can define custom query, but what if i want to add for example `Criteria` query to that class? Also i want methods like `findAll` to stay in repository.

This is what i try. First i created repository for `Post` entity:

```
package foo.bar.repository;

import foo.bar.model.Post;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long> {

}
```

Then i created abstract implementation class that extends interface and add my custom method to it:

```
package foo.bar.repository;

public abstract class PostRepositoryImpl implements PostRepository {

    public List<Post> someCustomMethod() {
        //some logic here
    }

}
```

It is even posible to do that? Maybe there is other approach to do that in hibernate. I was using [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) for long time, which is based on hibernate. There you just extend base repository class and add methods that you want.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to add an example of a custom method that executes a custom query. I hope I understood what you meant with your question.

**PersonRepository**

```
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long>{
    List<Post> getPostsOlderThanDate(Date date);
}
```

**PersonRepositoryImpl**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class PostRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<Post, Long> implements PostRepository {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public PostRepositoryImpl(EntityManager em) {
        super(Post.class, em);
        this.entityManager = em;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Post> getPostsOlderThanDate(Date date) {
        String query = ""; //create query
        TypedQuery<Post> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, Post.class);
        return typedQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
```

You then create your EntityManagerFactory bean (which you build with a Hibernate persistance provider, or however you set it up, it's up to you), and inject it into the constructor of the PersonRepositoryImpl bean.

```
<bean id="personRepository" class="com.package.PersonRepositoryImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

These would be the steps to provide some custom queries into your database.

**NOTE:** if you need help setting up your EntityManager just leave a comment addressed to me and I'll give you the spring config and dependencies.

Note, the suffix "Impl" is important.  Or it can be tweaked.  Find "repository-impl-postfix" at this article : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.spring for more details.

```
repository-impl-postfix

Defines the postfix to autodetect custom repository implementations. Classes whose names end with the configured postfix are considered as candidates. Defaults to Impl.
```

Comment: Hello @gabriel-ruiu , I can't find where to add PersonRepositoryImpl bean as you advised, is this something that still needs to be done?

Comment: @AdhamSabry, the bean definition is in the applicationContext.xml file. It is one of the ways to define beans in Spring. Maybe this will help ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414234/where-can-i-find-the-example-applicationcontext-xml-file/28418012  . But also googling for 'Spring xml configuration' will likely yield some information.

Comment: Any idea on how to add a "lookup strategy" method?  Optional<Post> findPostByPostNameEquals(String postname);  If I put this code inside of "interface PostRepository", the PostRepositoryImpl  wants an implementation.  But that goes against the grain of "lookup strategy"  :(    https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods