# Where can I find the example applicationContext.xml file

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

With Spring 3 distribution there was a project folder which was packaged in the distribution . This project folder had sample `applicationContext.xml` file which can be used . However when I have downloaded Spring 4 distribution from [here](http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/4.1.4.RELEASE/) it does not come with a project folder and I am not able to find the sample `applicationContext.xml`. Where can I find the example `applicationContext.xml` file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this for further information check [here](http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/).

Below sample contains configuration as follows:

- component-scan base com.foo which thinking as your root folder.
- Basic dataSource definition.
- Property place holder file(database.properties)
- Message Source for localization support.

**sample ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.foo" />


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: BTW ,We dont need ApplicationConetxt in Spring 4 .Annotations are there to do all job.I face thi issue and then removed this file "ApplicationConetxt" and it worked.

Comment: Yes this is not new feature of Spring but it is hard to find a working applicationContext.xml in all blogs.

Comment: Also, many Spring projects are written using xml files like the applicationContext.xml so learning this legacy format is good when encountering these.